# How could I make my UR5 in rviz mimic the real robot?

Tags: rviz, transform, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
My lab partner is controlling a couple of UR5 with our own nodes; so, i'd like to mimic them in rviz.
I guess I have to use robot_state_publisher; but I think that I should create a new node with the kinematic chain ,since I only have the TCP, which launch the jointstates mesagges.
But, Could I use the joint_states_publisher to simplify my work?
Thanks all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140831/how-could-i-make-my-ur5-in-rviz-mimic-the-real-robot?/) by [deulogio](https://answers.ros.org/users/12801/deulogio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although the [universal_robot](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot) stack also allows you to control the UR5 from ROS, you should be able to use it to just report state as well. It is part of the ROS-Industrial program.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [deulogio](https://answers.ros.org/users/12801/deulogio/) on 2014-03-20**:
Sorry gdvhoorn, but I am New in ROS and C++; Would I need a new program, implement by myself, for sending the jointstates messages from my UR5 or there is a specific node for this aim?
If I had to do this program, how do I find the kinematic chain and which messages need robot_state_publisher?
Have I to send this messages for joint_state_publisher before?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-03-26**:
For just state reporting, it should be enough to install the universal_robot stack and use the already available programs and launch files. Anything else would require you to create something new (or extend something that already exists).